# Struggling with a trigger between two mysql tables

Tags: java, mysql, database, triggers

I've read a lot both in books and even on the internet w/o success.
I'm trying to do user request case application.
Where all of the information in the case except comments will be saved in cases table and comments will be saved in a comments table.
I'm running Java through Netbeans and MySQL database. Each of which information is inserted and working like it is.

Case table:

```
CREATE TABLE `CASES` (
  `CASES_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TITEL` varchar(450) NOT NULL,
  `DESCRIPTION` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CASES_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comments Table

```
CREATE TABLE `CASE_COMMENTS` (
  `COMMENTSID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `COMMENTS` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CASE_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`COMMENTSID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

In my java code on execution I've this code to create comments line first if any comments is written

```
if (!getComments().isEmpty())
                {
                    commentStmt = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO CASE_COMMENTS(COMMENTS, Timed)" + "VALUES (?, ?)");
                    commentStmt.setString(1, getComments());
                    commentStmt.setTimestamp(2, sqlAndradDate);
                    commentStmt.executeUpdate();
                    succes = true;
                }
```

So my problem is that, when a comment row is created in the table, I also want it to get the corresponding caseID when saved.
I guess it's done with a trigger in somehow, I've tried all yesterdaya with a few of what I could find on Stackoverflow and other sites on the Internet. 
Is there someone with more experience with triggers that can help me out?

Comment: I don't see how a trigger would help. Your front-end is where the `Case_ID` is known (a user comments on a case I suppose, at this time you must know the Case_ID), so add the Case_ID in the normal insert statement.

Comment: I couldn't add the CASE_ID since it is unknown using auto_increment. 
I'm not in to triggers either, but after a lot of searching yesterday it seems that it was like that a lot of people described similar problems.

But I actually got it solved right now making the casetable inset execute first and then when inserting in the comments table case_id with the funkctionLAST_INSERT_ID(). Thought that I tried it yesterdey too, but I don't mind it's working now.

Comment: I've always used transactions when trying to get the last id to sync keys...